# Given series converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given:

$$ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac {n^{2.5}-1}{n^{6.5}+4}\right) $$

I know that a given series converges if $ lim: a_n \to 0$, in the above case for ${n \to \infty}$ the limit is 0. Hence, it should converge. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\lim a_n=0$ is not sufficient for a series to converge.  However, for large $n$ the series above is like $\sum 1/n^4$ and it converges because $\sum 1/n^A$ converges for all $A>1$.

Comment: It reduces to P series right?

Comment: The series can be compared to $\sum 1/n^4$ in the comparison test, I think. I'm not sure what a P series is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that a series converges if $\lim a_n=0$.  For example, consider
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1n.$$

Clearly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n=0$, but it is easily shown by the integral test that the series diverges.

Comment: Correct, it says that "If the series converges then lim is 0" its not a two way relationship.